# Working with strings in C, strcat and the strange behavior of terminating null! (#beginner)

Tags: c, string

I'm coming over from PHP, Ruby and JavaScript programming and I'm really finding my self at loss with C language, and in particular, regarding manipulating strings.

Getting to the bottom of it, I want to get an input from the user and store a text file with that name; However, everything happens but that. To be exact, as far as I could figure it out on my own, it is the terminating null that translates into � character.

Here is a standalone bug example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char year[4];
    scanf("%s", &year);
    char filename[8] = {};
    strcat(filename, year);
    char frmt[4] = ".txt";
    strcat(filename, frmt);
    printf("%s", filename);
    return 0;
}
```

From my Terminal:

```
$ gcc bug.c
$ ./a.out
2020
2020.txt2020
```

Here is another buggy example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char year[4];
    scanf("%s", &year);
    char filename[8];
    strcat(filename, year);
    strcat(filename, ".txt");
    printf("%s", filename);
    return 0;
}
```

Here the result is like this: `�2020.txt`

and the fix is something quite unusual, to my background, at least: *changing line 10 to `char filename[8] = {};`*

However, the most strange thing is that this same fix doesn't work over within a broader context of a code: https://vitualizersgit.xyz/teaching/sakile-c/-/blob/master/terminal.c

over there, the exact same code, doesn't even remotely function the same! There the `filename` becomes "2020�.txt" which means that `strcat` is **not overriding the terminating null**!

I'm seriously confused!

PS. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In C a string is a NUL terminated character sequence. So a four character string such as `2000` requires five `char`s. Thus `char year[4];` needs to be `char year[5];`

Comment: The `= {}` initializer is not valid in standard C.  It is valid in C++ though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `char year[4];`

To hold a string containing a four-digit year, you need space for four digits plus a terminating null character. Change this to `year[5]`.

> `scanf("%s", &year);`

For `%s`, `scanf` should be passed a pointer to the first character of the array, but `&year` is a pointer to the array. (The array and its first character start in the same place, but the *type* of `&year` is different from a pointer to a character.) A pointer to the first character of the array is `&year[0]`. However, you can just use `year`, and this will be automatically converted to a pointer to its first element.

Also, for safety, limit the `%s` to four characters. Change this code to `scanf("%4s", year);`.

> `char filename[8] = {};`

As above, you need one more element for a terminating null character, so change `[8]` to `[9]`.

Standard C requires at least one initializer, although some compilers may accept zero as an extension to the base language. However, there is no reason to rely on that. Change this to `char filename[9] = {0};` or, equivalently, `char filename[9] = "";`.

> `strcat(filename, year);`

This will work. However, another option is not to initialize `filename` (change the definition to `char filename[9];`) and use `strcpy` instead of `strcat`, so `strcpy(filename, year);`.

> `char frmt[4] = ".txt";`

Change `[4]` to `[5]`. In this case, you can also omit the dimension and let the compiler count the string. It will include the terminating null character: `char frmt[] = ".txt";`.

> `strcat(filename, frmt);`

This will work, but you do not need to put string literals in separate variables. You could use it directly, with `strcat(filename, ".txt");`, and delete the definition of `frmt`.

Answer (score 3):

`char filename[8];` does not initialize the array, so there is no guarantee that it contains any zero bytes. You must initialize array to zero by using `= {}` or `= ""`.

Also, 4 bytes is not enough to store `".txt"` or `"2020"`. You need 5 bytes so that you can also store the terminator, so `char frmt[5] = ".txt";`.